# Where to create navigationController so that I can use the pushViewController function

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I created a Tab-based application in Xcode 4 using the "Tabbed Application template".

In one of the view controllers, I have a Table View. Now when the user clicks on an item the table displays, I want a new view to appear.

I tried using:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailsViewController animated:YES];
```

but that doesn't work. On further inspection, I found out that `self.navigationController` is null, so I guess I have to create it somewhere.

Could you point me to where would I create it?

I am guessing it would be in the Application Delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method? Here's how it currently looks (this has been generated automatically by Xcode):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help, I've been stuck on this for a while and I can't seem to find out how to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to embed the view inside of a Navigation Controller. If your using the Storyboard, select the view (make sure it is outlined in blue) then go to **Editor->Embed in Navigation Controller.**

If you are doing it through code, then where you initially created this view, create a UINavigationController and initialize it with this view's view controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems the "Editor->Embed" does what I want!

Answer (score 0):

Your mainWindow.xib structure is going to look like this:[image]